# Being charged for EC2 even under AWS Free Tier pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS and just started to use AWS EC2 instances. I feel a lit bit confused of the free tier pricing. It says I can use 750 hours of EC2 freely per month. But it still charged me when my EC2 running hour is 428 hours. Is this billing related to other services?

[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts linked together?

Comment: You may want to create a support ticket and get better understanding of what the charges are for.

Comment: Was this bill for an entire month or a partial month? How many days?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth Actually I only have one account

Comment: @jarmod The bill is for Feb 2020 only which is approximately 10 days.

Comment: @Asdfg, thanks for your advice!